# Does all public assistance need to be listed as income when filing for bankruptcy?

Tags: bankruptcy

Asking with respect to the USA. I'm currently homeless and on food stamps and public assistance. I've googled and it's stated everywhere that foodstamps and public assistance cash need to be listed as income. That's fine, seems very cut and dried.

While I am staying in a shelter, my state welfare office is also paying my monthly fee for a storage facility, about $150. I don't get this money directly, they send a check to the storage facility. Do I need to include this as income?

Likewise, I don't pay any rent, but the welfare office does pay the shelter an amount for me residing there. Should I also declare that amount as income? Should I even declare it as rent, since I don't pay it directly?

Comment: Listed as income where/for what purpose?  For taxes, or (based on the tag) a bankruptcy proceeding?  Also, what jurisdiction are you located in?  Based on the terminology, I'm assuming the United States, but it's not clear from the question.

Comment: @RyanM I will edit the question to be more clear, but yes both your assumptions are correct.